# Emacs can't run external programs

Tags: call-process, permissions

I'm running Emacs 27.2 on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9 virtual machine, on which I do not have admin privileges. I reach this VM either using TigerVNC or plain old SSH. This installation of Emacs apparently has some kind of permissions problem, as it can't run external programs like "ls". Here's the problem in a nutshell: In the scratch buffer, run

```
(executable-find "ls") ^J
"/bin/ls"
(call-process "ls") ^J
126
```

So Emacs can find the executable "ls", but does not have permission to run it; hence the [126 exit code](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html). If Emacs is started from the command line (i.e. `emacs -q -no-start-init`) executing `(call-process "ls")` generates the message "Cannot allocate memory" on the command line as well as the exit code 126.

Chasing down the executable, `/bin/emacs` is a link to `/etc/alternatives/emacs` (I think, not sure) which in turn is a link to the real executable `/usr/bin/emacs-27.2`, which has permissions 755. Right next to it is a file `/usr/bin/emacs-27.2.pdmp`, which [apparently](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Building-Emacs.html) is a binary compiled from Emacs lisp code. This file has permissions 644. Both are user "root", group "root".

The sysadmins are busy/distracted/tired, don't use Emacs themselves, and asked me to run down the problem, which they appear to believe lies in the bowels of Emacs somewhere. I, OTOH, believe that this is a straightforward permissions problem that is the sysadmin's proper bailiwick.

Unfortunately, to get any response, it appears that I have to prove a negative; that is, Emacs is not the problem. So I ask you: is there any way that Emacs *could* be the problem?

Comment: Does `(shell-command "ls")` work?

Comment: @shynur It behaves exactly as `(call-process"ls")`; exit code 126.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the file permissions of the Emacs binary, that’s for sure. That just tells you who is allowed to run Emacs, nothing else. 0755 allows everyone to run it, but only root can modify the binary.

The OS is RHEL, so it has a sophisticated security system called SELinux which has fine–grained control over all aspects of the system. Run `getenforce` at the command line to see if it is enforcing a policy. If it is, then check `/var/log/audit/audit.log` to see if that policy is what is preventing Emacs from running other programs.

Comment: Interesting. When I ssh into the VM and type `getenforce` at the command line, it returns "Disabled". I don't have access to the `/var/log/audit/` directory, so I can't see `audit.log`, but presumably that doesn't matter since no policy is being enforced.

Comment: Yep. Maybe it really is `ls` just running out of memory then.